# JS переместить элемент в списке родительского DOM

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть содержащий список изображений div. Каждое изображение обернуто своим div.

Через каждые 3 секунды фокус переходит к следующему изображению.

В содержащем div видно только 3 изображения, фокус - на среднем, и при переходе фокуса, соответственно, верхний элемент списка должен перемещаться в конец списка.

Структура:

```
<div>
  <div><img class='i1' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i2 focused' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i3' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i4' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i5' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i6' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i7' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i8' src='#'/></div>
</div>
```

должно стать при перемещении фокуса

```
<div>
  <div><img class='i2' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i3 focused' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i4' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i5' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i6' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i7' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i8' src='#'/></div>
  <div><img class='i1' src='#'/></div>
</div>
```

Так понимаю, должен использовать appendChild/removeChild, получив оьект div-обертки изображения.

Есть ли другой способ?

Только на JS/ES6.

Comment: зачем другой способ?

Comment: @Igor я надеюсь есть способ привязать сами элементы к массиву и делать просто shift, что будет смещать и в дереве DOM эти элементы...

Comment: Было бы удобней если бы не было div для каждого элемента, можете поставить img display: block

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько там изображения разных размеров, поэтому нужен див, что бы вместить фиксировано...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С дивами:

```js
run()

function run () {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img')
  const focused = [...images].find(i => i.classList.contains('focused'))
  const parent = focused.parentNode
  const previous = parent.previousElementSibling
  const next = parent.nextElementSibling
  
  focused.classList.remove('focused')
  next.querySelector('img').classList.add('focused')
  // добавляет в конец
  previous.parentNode.appendChild(previous) 

  setTimeout(run, 1000)
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img.focused {
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div><img class='i2' src='https://picsum.photos/60/40/?random=1'/></div>
  <div><img class='i3 focused' src='https://picsum.photos/50/50/?random=2'/></div>
  <div><img class='i4' src='https://picsum.photos/70/70/?random=3'/></div>
  <div><img class='i5' src='https://picsum.photos/80/50/?random=4'/></div>
  <div><img class='i6' src='https://picsum.photos/90/60/?random=5'/></div>
  <div><img class='i7' src='https://picsum.photos/100/50/?random=6'/></div>
  <div><img class='i8' src='https://picsum.photos/100/80/?random=7'/></div>
  <div><img class='i1' src='https://picsum.photos/100/70/?random=8'/></div>
</div>
```

Без дивов:

```js
run()

function run () {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img')
  const focused = [...images].find(i => i.classList.contains('focused'))
  const previous = focused.previousElementSibling
  const next = focused.nextElementSibling
  
  focused.classList.remove('focused')
  next.classList.add('focused')
  // добавляет в конец
  previous.parentNode.appendChild(previous) 

  setTimeout(run, 1000)
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img.focused {
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class='i2' src='https://picsum.photos/60/40/?random=1'/>
  <img class='i3 focused' src='https://picsum.photos/50/50/?random=2'/>
  <img class='i4' src='https://picsum.photos/70/70/?random=3'/>
  <img class='i5' src='https://picsum.photos/80/50/?random=4'/>
  <img class='i6' src='https://picsum.photos/90/60/?random=5'/>
  <img class='i7' src='https://picsum.photos/100/50/?random=6'/>
  <img class='i8' src='https://picsum.photos/100/80/?random=7'/>
  <img class='i1' src='https://picsum.photos/100/70/?random=8'/>
</div>
```

Comment: СпасиБо! хорошо выглядит и работает.